# Directadmin + Nginx + php fpm + location: File not found

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location, directadmin

I've a nginx conf in Direct Admin with a custom location:

Code:

```
location /reset-password {
     alias /home/**/domains/**.**/public_html/api/frontend-scripts/resetPassword;
     include /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/**/nginx_php.conf;
}
```

This isn't working; nginx shows 'File not found.' for all PHP related files in the browser. Plain HTML is working fine.

I've tried several other solutions, i.e.:

Code:

```
location /reset-password {
    alias /home/**/domains/**.**/public_html/api/frontend-scripts/resetPassword;
    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
       try_files $uri index.php;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include /etc/nginx/nginx_limits.conf;
       if (-f $request_filename)
       {
           fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/php56/sockets/**.sock;
       }
    }
 }
```

All of them are giving a 'File not found.' in the browser.

So it probably has something to do with phpfpm, but I'm out of options. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `alias` with PHP is always problematic as the `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` statement is no longer valid.

You could use:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

But an [open bug in `nginx`](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) makes the use of `try_files` with `alias` a little unpredictable.

My preferred solution is to invisibly rewrite the URI so that a [`root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) can be used:

```
location ^~ /reset-password {
    rewrite ^/reset-password(.*)$ /resetPassword$1 last;
}
location ^~ /resetPassword {
    root /home/**/domains/**.**/public_html/api/frontend-scripts;
    ...
}
```

Also notice that the `^~` modifier causes [these prefix location blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to take precedence over other regular expression location blocks at the same level (e.g. another `location ~ \.php$` block) should there be one.

Comment: Richard, thank you very much, your solution worked out-of-the-box

Comment: Aaah, you are a lifesafer! Have been struggling with this for hours now. The fastcgi_param did the trick!